# HTML Table Header Not In Line With Table Body When Scrolled Horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

Have an html table positioned at the center of the page. The table has a fixed header when scrolled vertically but the header does not scroll in line with the body of the table when scrolled vertically. The table is presented below..

This is after the page loads.
[image]

Table after scrolling horizontally to the right. Note that the 
table head is offset from the body.
[image]

Table after scrolling horizontally to the left.Note that header does not start from One.
[image]

The code is presented below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTableBody();
  $(window).resize(setTableBody);
  $(".table-body").scroll(function() {
 $(".table-header").offset({
   left: -1 * this.scrollLeft
 });
  });
});

function setTableBody() {
  $(".table-body").height($(".inner-container").height() - $(".table-header").height());
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.outer-container {
  background-color: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10em;;
  left: 10em;
  right: 200em;
  bottom: 40em;
  height:400px;
  width:500px;
}
.inner-container {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position:relative;
}
.table-header {
  position: relative;
}
.table-body {
  overflow: auto;
}
.header-cell {
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: left;
  height: 40px;
}
.body-cell {
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: left;
}
.col1,
.col3,
.col4,
.col5 {
  width: 120px;
  min-width: 120px;
}
.col2 {
  min-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='scroll.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<header> 
<a href="/datacentre/index.php" title="Return to the homepage" id="logo">
  <img src="/datacentre/images/cagd_logo.jpg" alt="CAGD logo" 
  style="width:30px;height:30px;"/>
</a>
<span class="headerspan">CAGD Data Centre</span>
<a href="/datacentre/webhelp/index.htm" title="Return to the homepage" id="helpfile">
  help
</a>
</header>
<section id="content">
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="inner-container">
 <div class="table-header">
   <table id="headertable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
   <th class="header-cell col1">One</th>
   <th class="header-cell col2">Two</th>
   <th class="header-cell col3">Three</th>
   <th class="header-cell col4">Four</th>
   <th class="header-cell col5">Five</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
   </table>
 </div>
 <div class="table-body">
   <table id="bodytable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
   <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
   <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
   <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
   <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
   <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
   <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
   <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
   <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
   <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
   <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
   <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
   <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
   <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
   <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
   <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
   <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
   <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
   <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
   <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
   <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
   <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
   <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
   <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
   <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
   <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
   <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
   <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
   </table>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>You can achieve same effect and behavior with pure CSS</strike>

HTML Table Header In Line With Table Body When Scrolled Horizontally

OP pointed that with Pure CSS, header of table will not be fixed and move with the table body when scroll down the so back to square one to jQuery solution,

After banging my head with the code, realized that the problem table header jumps to left and not aligned with table body causing by the `left:10em` property in `outer-container` selector, so easy fix is that calculate the `10em` in `px` which is equal to `160px` and adjust the margin when scroll left.

```
function setTableBody() {
    $(".table-body").height(
    $(".inner-container").height() - $(".table-header").height());
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    setTableBody();
    $(window).resize(setTableBody);
    $(".table-body").scroll(function () {
        $(".table-header").offset({
            left: 160 - this.scrollLeft
        });
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dcuz3z9y/1/)

**Better Alternate**

Let the jQuery do all the leg work for you and calculate the `outer-container` left margin dynamically.

```js
function setTableBody() {
    $(".table-body").height(
    $(".inner-container").height() - $(".table-header").height());
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var marginLeft = $(".outer-container").position().left; //Create var and calculate the difference from left
    setTableBody();
    $(window).resize(setTableBody);
    $(".table-body").scroll(function () {
        $(".table-header").offset({
            left: marginLeft - this.scrollLeft //minus the difference while table header scroll with table body
        });
    });
});
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.outer-container {
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5em;
    left: 10em;
    right: 200em;
    bottom: 40em;
    height:200px;
    width:500px;
}
.inner-container {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position:relative;
}
.table-header {
    position: relative;
}
.table-body {
    overflow: auto;
}
.header-cell {
    background-color: yellow;
    text-align: left;
    height: 40px;
}
.body-cell {
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: left;
}
.col1, .col3, .col4, .col5 {
    width: 120px;
    min-width: 120px;
}
.col2 {
    min-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
<a href="/datacentre/index.php" title="Return to the homepage" id="logo">
  <img src="/datacentre/images/cagd_logo.jpg" alt="CAGD logo" 
  style="width:30px;height:30px;"/>
</a>

<span class="headerspan">CAGD Data Centre</span>

<a href="/datacentre/webhelp/index.htm" title="Return to the homepage" id="helpfile">
  help
</a>

    <section id="content">
        <div class="outer-container">
            <div class="inner-container">
                <div class="table-header">
                    <table id="headertable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="header-cell col1">One</th>
                                <th class="header-cell col2">Two</th>
                                <th class="header-cell col3">Three</th>
                                <th class="header-cell col4">Four</th>
                                <th class="header-cell col5">Five</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="table-body">
                    <table id="bodytable">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="body-cell col1">body row1</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col2">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col3">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col4">body row2</td>
                                <td class="body-cell col5">body row2 en nog meer</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

[Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/dcuz3z9y/2/)

Comment: the table has a fixed header but your solution does not provide a fixed header solution.

Comment: thanks for the answer  but can we calculate the outer-container left margin margin dynamically by use of a function. Better than hard coding.

Comment: yeah the 2nd JS code is calculating the `outer-container left margin` dynamically, `var marginLeft = $(".outer-container").position().left;` and then adjusting the header `left: marginLeft - this.scrollLeft`, use the 2nd JS code

Comment: I am not able to get my table header and body to align together in column width. Is there any suggestion.

Comment: can you create a fiddle, it will be alot easier to solve the problem but yes there is a way, calculate the width of  table head th and, table body tr and set them equal

Comment: Yes  that is what I mean

Comment: how much room I have if I have to make changes, reason you have per-defined width in CSS `Col1 to Col5` selectors and this may be a problem.

Comment: you can make as many changes as possible. I am really interested in a solution.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you create two tables in the html code, one for the header and one for the body, and this causes the offset.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that @Shehary's solution only works for LTR tables, and the given function

```
    $(".table-body").scroll(function () {
    $(".table-header").offset({
        left: marginLeft - this.scrollLeft //minus the difference while table header scroll with table body
    });
});
```

didn't work for me.

I got it to work by changing the container's minimum width to avoid horizontal scroll, that way the horizontal scroll is the window's scroll and there are no re-sizing issues or calculations.

Also, I defined the column's width with percent, so I could have a more responsive table.
So if you can live with the minimum width constraint, this is a pure CSS solution.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shirara/rgkth4ja/1/)